# Facebook API Error Code: 191 on facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing a Facebook app. When I attempt to get an access token, I get the following message:

```
An error occurred with test. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

https://apps.facebook.com/fb_invite_app/----->URL
I've configured the

Site URL     https://safe-gorge-5005.herokuapp.com/
   Canvas URL   same as above
   Canvas Page  URL
 and my php code has define("FACEBOOK_CANVAS_URL", 'URL');

What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you give **App Domains** in app settings page , this may be one of the reason for getting this error